# Sorting by month in an array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I need an array that gives me `@idea.id` sorted by `@idea.created_at.month`

For example:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

where ids 1, 2, and 3 have `@idea.created_at.month = 1` and so on through `month = 12`.

```
@ideas_by_month = Array.new(12){Array.new}
@ideas.each do |idea|
  month = idea.created_at.month
  @ideas_by_month[month-1] << idea.id
end
```

By the example, I'd need `@ideas_by_month[0]` to give me ids `1`, `2`, `3`.

This currently adds all of the ideas into one slot `[]`, and isn't sorting properly.  How can I change it to make my array look like the example?

Comment: what do you mean by isn't properly? can you show what you get and what is wrong?

Comment: It gives me [Idea.all] with no 12 slots, no sorting into 12 slots.  The data is from May and June, so there should be at least 2 slots filled.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov do you see any other reason this (edited) array wouldn't be working? Its still giving the same output I described above.

Comment: Please stop changing your question. You originally had `@ideas_by_month = Array.new(12,[])`. @steenslag then told you it should be `Array.new(12) {[]}`. He did not mean for you to make that correction in your question. By doing so, you render his answer meaningless (unless readers read through your edits).  Understand? The only edits you should make are to clarify, and where appropriate, make clear it's an edit (e.g., "Edit: the array....").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not in your << call, but in your creation of the @ideas_by_month Array. [From the Ruby API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays)...

> ```
> Array.new(3, true) #=> [true, true, true]
> ```
>
> Note that the second argument populates the array with references to
>   the same object. Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you
>   need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as
>   Symbols, numbers, true or false.

So, when you're pushing into any of the nested Arrays, it's all referencing the same space in memory. Which is why it appears that every id is getting pushed into every nested Array.

Instead declare your Array with a block:

```
@ideas_by_month = Array.new(12) { Array.new }
```

...which would look like this fully implemented as a class method:

**idea.rb**

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.ideas_by_month
    @ideas_by_month = Array.new(12){Array.new}
    Idea.all.each do |idea|
      month = idea.created_at.month
      @ideas_by_month[month-1] << idea.id
    end
    return @ideas_by_month
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: After trying this it shows just one slot [ ] with all the ideas in it, with no separate slots.  You see anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: The loop itself returns an array of all the looped-through items. Are you returning @ideas_by_month once again at the end? (assuming this lives in a class method)

Answer (score 3):

`Array.new(12,[])` gives you 12 references to the same array. `Array.new(12){Array.new}` creates 12 different arrays.

Comment: good catch, didn't try the method of arrays creation described in ops post

Comment: This is def part of the answer, but gives me the same output.  I've edited above with the current array, do you see any other reason it wouldn't be working?

Comment: @VirgeAssault what is the result of `p @ideas.group_by{|idea|  idea.created_at.month }` ?